# How to apply CSS only to numbers in paragraph? (without <span>)

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to apply CSS only to numbers in paragraphs without wrapping numbers in `span`s?

```
<p>Text and numbers: 123</p>
<p>123 and text</p>
```

Are there any selectors? In jQuery, maybe. Or somehow parse it using javascript...

**Expected result:**

---

[image]

Comment: Wrap the numbers in spans. it's the only way. css styles can only be applied to elements.

Comment: Currently, CSS has no way to distinguish numbers from non-numbers.

Comment: you have to wrap numbers in elements, like spans or anything else

Comment: Or write a plugin in jQuery that parse your document and wrap the numbers in paragraphs in spans with the class you want.

Comment: You could write some javascript that would add the spans for you... @sabotero beat me to the punch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this with only CSS. Since you also marked your question with a jQuery tag, you can however do it this way:

```
$('p').html(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fs6Mb/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you want without wrapping the desired text strings in elements, like spans or anything else.

With jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('p').each(function() {
            var el = $(this),
                html = el.html();

            html = html.replace(/(\d)/gi, "<span class='numbers'>$1</span>");

            el.html(html);

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
$('p').html(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="here_you_class">$1</span>');
});
```