# Apply css just to digits

Tags: css, colors, wicket, digits

how can I apply a css-class, so that in that div, just the digits will have a specific color? I am using wicket to generate the content of the div.

here is my code for ex:

```
<div class="coloredDigitsClass">
    <div wicket:id="axMax125At10V"></div>
</div>
```

and the generated text will look like this "Roni, Type @ 4.5V, 90°C"

but it could be something like this as well: "Roni, Maxi/125°C @ 10V"

I want that just "4.5" and "90" in the first example to be colored in red.
and in the 2nd example, "125" and "10".

Comment: If you want to solve this with Wicket, you can intercept the `onComponentTagBody` method and iterate the strings characters to build up a new string with digits replaced with `<span class="foo">SOME_DIGIT</span>`

Answer (score 0):

A solution with CSS would be using the [`unicode-range` descriptor](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css-fonts-3-20131003/#unicode-range-desc), as was also suggested in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679719/how-to-apply-css-to-only-numbers-in-a-text-inside-or-any-pp-element)**. Alternatively use jQuery as was suggested in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076938/how-to-apply-css-only-to-numbers-in-paragraph-without-span)**.